# how we can use 2 UIPicker on the same controller?

Tags: swift, uipickerview

Xcode 11 ; Swift 4

How I can use 2 UIPicker on the same controller?

For example in the code below I would like to simple compare value of UIPicker 1 and value of UIPicker2. Thanks!

It should be something like this:

Here my example:

```
if row1 == 0 && row2 == 0 {     
} 
else if row1 == 0 && row2 == 1 {
} 
else {
}
```

Real code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

var data1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var data2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var Calculator = "0"

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource,        UIPickerViewDelegate {
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int     {

   return data1.count

}

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
    titleForRow row: Int,
    forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return data1[row]
}

@IBOutlet weak var Calculator: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var from: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var to: UIPickerView!

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if row == 0 {

    } else if row == 1 {

    } else if row == 2 {

    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()
    self.from.dataSource = self
    self.from.delegate = self
    self.to.dataSource = self
    self.to.delegate = self   
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
} 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use sth like this:

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int     {
        if pickerView == from {
            return data1.count
        } else {
            return data2.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == from {
            return data1[row]
        } else {
            return data2[row]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let index1 = from.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let index2 = to.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let row1 = data1[index1]
        let row2 = data2[index2]

        calculator.text = "\(row1) - \(row2)"
    }
```

Any UIKit delegate functions will receive the calling component as the first parameter you can use that to check which component is performing that function.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set each picker tag value and use that to identify each one, like this:

First set a tag value for each picker

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()
self.from.dataSource = self
self.from.delegate = self
self.from.tag = 1

self.to.dataSource = self
self.to.delegate = self   
self.to.tag = 2

}
```

Then use that tag value to identify each picker:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return data1[row]
    } else {
        return data2[row]
    }
}
```

Comment: hello Alejandro. Are you good with TableView Pickers? please email me thank you. miketradr@gmail.com